# How To Get Foreign Key Information In .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlconnection

I'm trying to use the .NET `GetSchema` method to retrieve metadata about some tables in SQL Server.
I can get back Columns information, like data type and size, but when I try "ForeignKeys" it doesn't tell me the name of the related table or the related column name.
Below is my current code.
Can this be done with `GetSchema`?  If not, I'll resort to using SQL queries on the system tables or information tables, whatever they are called.
If you don't know the `GetSchema` answer feel free to suggest a good SQL query.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    string[] restrictions = new string[4];
    restrictions[1] = schemaName;
    restrictions[2] = tableName;
    DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("ForeignKeys", restrictions);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm going to use SMO objects if I can get them to run on my web host.  I'm getting a new error that SqlClrProvider can't be found.  I can't find that dll on my local machine, but SMO works on my local machine.  Edit: I found the SqlClrProvider.dll, added the reference, re-published to my web host and it ran perfectly.  Problem solved using SMO objects to get the foreign key metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, foreign key relationships can be composed of more than one column.  Here is a query that I use for my FK column mapping:

```
select 
        IS_KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
        IS_KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
        IS_KCU1.TABLE_SCHEMA FK_TABLE_SCHEMA,
        IS_KCU1.TABLE_NAME FK_TABLE_NAME,
        IS_KCU1.COLUMN_NAME FK_COLUMN_NAME,
        IS_KCU2.TABLE_SCHEMA REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA,
        IS_KCU2.TABLE_NAME REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
        IS_KCU2.COLUMN_NAME REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS IS_RC 

        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE IS_KCU1 
        on IS_KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = IS_RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG  
        and IS_KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = IS_RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        and IS_KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = IS_RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 

        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE IS_KCU2 
        on IS_KCU2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = IS_RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG  
        and IS_KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = IS_RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        and IS_KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = IS_RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        and IS_KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION = IS_KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION
```